# Windows compatible USB > LAN adapter compatible?

Tags: usb, compatibility

Does anyone have any experience if these cheap USB 2 > Ethernet adapters like sold on ebay for 1 or $2 work with mac. They say only windows compatible, but I can't imagine why they wouldn't work on mac too.

[image]

Comment: You might have to contact the seller to see if it is compatible (or someone that have the same model adapter). If you already have the adapter, you can plug it in and check.

Comment: Asking if "cheap USB to Ethernet adapters are compatible with Mac" is way too much of a broad question.  Please consider narrowing it down to a specific device.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:
Googling for the model of the device and mac "KY-RD9700 mac" brings up a list of solutions which involve setting `csrutil disable` in safe mode. So they should work.

Comment: Disabling SIP to get a USB device to work should be a **huge** red flag that this is not a reliable/safe product to use.  You are essentially turning of a critical security component to make a peripheral device work.

Comment: I agree with @Allan. Turning off the System Integrity Protection configuration just to use an ethernet adapter is a very unsatisfying answer to me as it is too dangerous.